# Здравствуйте!А как скачать и установить Python?

Tags: python

Как скачать и установить Python 3.6.3? Нигде инструкции я не нашёл.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Никаких подробностей - ни ОС, ни что конкретно непонятно...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно, например, с сайта https://www.python.org/downloads/. 
Вот прямо ссылка на скачивание нужной версии: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-363/

Или, если у тебя Мак - в терминале brew install python3